# Using git to manage combinations of branches in same directory

Tags: git, branch

I'm using git in a nonstandard way, I have a mixture of files in a directory where each comes from a different branch. I'm using this combination of commands to modify a file:

```
git fetch -f --all                      # Synch revision info with repository.
git checkout -f remotes/$REPO/$BRANCH -- $FILE         # Update file contents.
vim $FILE                                              # Make changes.
git add $FILE                                          # Record the changes.
git commit -o -- $FILE                                 # Commit the changes.
git push -f $REPO heads/$BRANCH         # Push to branch in repository.
```

This *almost* does what I want, from different systems I can bring down the latest changes to any given file without affecting any of the others. What I'm missing, though, is that there's no edit-trail of the changes that had been made to the file. It looks like it's re-rooting the branch to the latest commit each time, as opposed to chaining the commits for that branch.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I've been going through the git documentation, but everything is described in terms of a work-flow that's unrelated to what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: I recognize that RCS would be a more appropriate tool for this kind of work-flow, where each file has it's own repository file. I'm using git because there are servers visible across the internet, and given the richness of the git tools, I believe I can make this work.


I'd like to be able to do this using branching, as opposed to creating a git repository for each file. BitBucket gives a nice view of all the branches that wouldn't look so pretty as repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you replace `git checkout -f remotes/$REPO/$BRANCH -- $FILE` with

```
...
git merge --no-ff --no-commit remotes/$REPO/$BRANCH
git reset -- *  #unstage all changes
git add $FILE
git checkout .  #cancel changes to all files but $FILE
...
```

Then you keep some history of where the modifications come from.

Comment: (dummy comment here -- I can't seem to delete what was going to write)

Answer (score 1):

So far it looks like changing

```
git checkout -f remotes/$REPO/$BRANCH -- $FILE
```

to

```
git checkout -m remotes/$REPO/$BRANCH -- $FILE
```

makes it work the way I want it to. Do you see any problems with this? I'm seeing a few inconsistencies, but they have to do with operations that I'm not describing here.